# Cleaning remote Git branches

Tags: git, git-branch, git-remote

I have moved an SVN repo to Git and probably due to a number of clonings, I'm now left with a bunch of branches that look like

```
BranchA
origin/BranchA
remotes/BranchA
remotes/origin/BranchA
remotes/origin/origin/BranchA
```

i.e. the same branch is listed a number of times. How can I clean this mess up. There are > 50 branches, some are not needed at all, and for the rest I'd be happy with just having them once.

EDIT:

This is what git remote show origin looks like for a certain case:

```
Remote branches:
BranchA tracked
origin/BranchA tracked
```

...

```
Local branches configured for 'git pull':
origin/BranchA merges with remote BranchA
```

...

```
Local refs configured for 'git push':
BranchA pushes to BranchA (up to date)
origin/BranchA pushes to origin/BranchA (up to date)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can remove these branches by using this command:

```
git push origin :branch_name
```

To remove the `BranchA` branch:

```
git push origin :BranchA
```

To remove the `origin/BranchA` branch:

```
git push origin :origin/BranchA
```

Alternatively you could use `git branch -dr BranchA` and so on.

Remove every branch except `BranchA` and `origin/BranchA`. You may have deleted the `origin` remote, in which case you should remove the `remotes` remote and re-add it as the `origin` remote.

Comment: Which ones should I remove? Let's say I want to keep one of the BranchA's, would it be remotes/BranchA?

Comment: *git rm* works on files, not branches (neither local or “remote tracking”). The syntax of the arguments seems to indicate that you intended to write about using *git push* to delete branches out of the remote repository. The OP also has some number of local and “remote-tracking” branches to delete, too (`git branch -d` along with `git branch -dr` or `git remote prune`).

Comment: @Chris Johnsen: you're right, I should have use `git push` or `git branch -dr`. I'll update the answer to reflect this now.

Comment: I found a answer in this topic [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3184742/17814321)