# Deleting a really badly named git branch

Tags: git, git-branch

I accidentally created a branch called "remotes/origin/remotes/origin/aclark" and can't delete it with:

git branch -d remotes/origin/remotes/origin/aclark

Git says:

error: branch 'remotes/origin/remotes/origin/aclark' not found.

I tried some of the suggestions here: [Deleting a badly named git branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1192180/deleting-a-badly-named-git-branch), but they are geared more towards bad branch names that start with "--".

Is there any way an end user can delete this branch or do I need a git admin? (The branch in question lives at gitorious).

Thanks

Alex

Comment: Similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3810242/cleaning-remote-git-branches

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is a remote branch, so you need to delete it on the server. To do that, you need to push an empty reference.

```
$ git push origin :remotes/origin/aclark
```

Note, the syntax of the `git push` command is:

```
$ git push <remote> <local-reference>:<remote-branch-name>
```

So in the case, we are pushing an empty reference, and the remote name is the name of the branch we want to destroy. In your case, the branch name "remotes/origin/remotes/origin/aclark" indicates that it is a remote branch on the remote server name "origin", and the name on the distant server is "remotes/origin/aclark".

The other client will need to issue the following commands to have the branch removed from their local repository (if they fetched when the invalid branch existed):

```
$ git fetch origin
$ git remote prune origin
```

More information can be found in the [git-push](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-push.html) and [git-remote](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-remote.html) manpages.

Comment: Thanks! This has just begun to sink in. And indeed, git push origin :remotes/origin/aclark did the trick. Thanks again!