# When deleting remote git branch "error: unable to push to unqualified destination"

Tags: git

I'm trying to delete a remote git branch with

```
git push origin :my_remote_branch
```

and getting:

```
error: unable to push to unqualified destination: my_remote_branch
The destination refspec neither matches an existing ref on the remote nor
begins with refs/, and we are unable to guess a prefix based on the source ref.
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@example.com:/myrepo'
```

these are my current branches

```
git branch -a
* develop
  master
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  remotes/origin/develop
  remotes/origin/my_remote_branch

git branch -r --merged
  origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  origin/develop
  origin/master
```

Any ideas on how I can get rid of this branch would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you try a `git fetch`to see if it fixed that non-existing remote name? Did you try to go in your `.git\refs\remotes\origin` and delete the `my_remote_branch` file, to see if that is enough?

Comment: did `git fetch` but that didn't help. Will try to search for a more straight forward solution before trying to delete the file manually.

Comment: try to delete or at least move that file: it contains only the SHA1 of the tip of that branch.

Comment: You must do `git fetch -p` to get rid of stale tracking branches.

Answer (score 286, accepted):

The fact that `refs/remotes/origin/my_remote_branch` exists in your local repository does not imply `refs/heads/my_remote_branch` exists in the `origin` remote repository.

Do `git fetch -p origin` to make `refs/remotes/origin/my_remote_branch` go away if it's already deleted in origin. The `-p` option tells fetch to delete any tracking branches that no longer exist in the corresponding remotes; by default they are kept around.

Comment: pruning did not help! while `git push origin --delete origin/feature/x` gave me error about non-existence ref `git push origin :feature/x` did delete the branch. So I guess `git push origin --delete <branchName>` should not include origin in the branchName (?) but it is bash-completed which is confusing.

Comment: @dashesy, you were in different situation than the original asker. In the original question, the problem is that the remote branch was _already deleted_, presumably by somebody else, so only the local had to be synced. While you are deleting the remote. Indeed, the command should be `git push origin --delete feature/x`, because you are giving the name of the branch _at origin_, and it does _not_ have that prefix there (the two forms are otherwise synonymous anyway).

Comment: @JanHudec makes sense. Bash complete is smart when using `:` to not include `origin` but it completes as `origin/branch_name` instead of simply `branch_name` when using the `--delete` variant.

Answer (score 62):

Found question [cleaning up old remote git branches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3184555/cleaning-up-old-remote-git-branches) and this did the trick

```
git branch -r -d origin/my_remote_branch
```

Comment: I've been trying to do exactly this for around an hour now, thanks a lot!

Comment: This does not delete the remote branch. If you go a git fetch you will see the branch again. It just remove it from your local list of remote branch.

Comment: @PatrickDesjardins exactly `git push origin :my_remote_branch` deletes the branch from the remote and `git branch -r -d origin/my_remote_branch` removes it from my local list of remote branches

Answer (score 14):

I ran across this when trying to delete a remote branch that had already been deleted. All that was needed was a prune:

```
git remote prune origin
```

Answer (score 6):

Try following two options to delete remote branch forcibly

Option 1

```
get push origin --delete <branchName>
```

Option 2

```
git fetch -p origin
git branch -r -d origin/<branchName>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
git branch -r -d origin/my_remote_branch
```

was not enough for me. Before I had to go to server and work with git directory directly (which is dangerous and ugly) to remove the branch:

```
ssh mygitserver
su - git
cd /home/git/repositories/my_remote_branch.git/
git  --git-dir=. --work-tree=/tmp/ branch -D my_remote_branch
```

Comment: It's not just dangerous and ugly, it's also _wrong_. For one thing, this question is about deleting the branch locally when it _has_ been deleted at remote. And for the other, deleting a branch from remote is just a matter of `git push origin :my_remote_branch`. Mind the colon.

Comment: You're right Jan, that `git push origin :my_remote_branch` is normal way. This ugly and dangerous way is when this does not work (e.g. due to misconfigured git).

Answer (score 2):

For me the problem was, that this was my default branch on github. I changed default branch, then delete operation was succeeded.

Hope it helps to someone

Answer (score 1):

I have the similar problem. 
First went to this discussion, however I couldn't solve the problem until I saw https://stackoverflow.com/a/32147743/4209849.

**which simply add a tip on distinguishing `origin/my-branch-name` and `my-branch-name`.**

To be specific, I should use:

```
git push origin :my_remote_branch
```

instead of

```
git push origin :origin/my_remote_branch
```

This solved my problem at least, hope it would help others as well.

Answer (score 0):

Had this same issue, I manually edited my `./.git/config` file to include:

```
[branch "branchName"]
remote = origin
merge = refs/heads/branchName
```

Which resulted into: `error: src refspec branchName matches more than one.` This I fixed by running `$git tag -d branchName`.
After which I was able to push the new branch to upstream.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:
I created the remote branch on github UI and then pushed my local branch which had the same name to it.  Try it in case other ways dont work.
Other way would be creating a new branch locally and pushing an empty branch and later cherry-pick your commit and push again to your remote.