# How to solve "error: unable to push to unqualified destination: HEAD"

Tags: git

I have a revision like `A -> B -> C -> D -> E`. I tried to rollback to `C` and commit that as a new revision `F` but it seems it's not the right way to do it: I `git checkout C` and then do some changes and then `git commit`. However, when I `git push origin HEAD` it complains that:

`error: unable to push to unqualified destination: HEAD
The destination refspec neither matches an existing ref on the remote nor
begins with refs/, and we are unable to guess a prefix based on the source ref.`

As [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10292480/when-deleting-remote-git-branch-error-unable-to-push-to-unqualified-destinatio) suggests, I tried `git fetch -p origin` but it didn't work. Still got the same error message.

My question is that how can I get rid of this situation and fulfill my original goal (rollback to `C` and commit that to `F`)?

Also, as this question suggests, I can:

```
git rm -r .
git checkout HEAD~3 .
git commit
```

but I don't really want to `git rm -r .` because there are a lot of untracked but useful stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you're looking for `git revert`.  In your case:

```
git revert E D
```

Afterwards you can rebase to squash the two reverting commits together.

Comment: Thanks. That works. BTW I solved the `git push origin` problem by `checkout` my original branch again. Then `git revert` as you suggest.