# git delete remotes: remote refs do not exist

Tags: git, git-remote

### In short;

- How can I delete remote multiple merged remotes?

### More background;

I have a git repo with tens of remotes which have been merged into master.  I can delete these remotes one at a time by using:

```
git push --delete origin myBranch-1234
```

However this is a slow and tedious process for all remotes.  So I'm trying this command:

```
git branch -r --merged | grep origin | grep -v master | xargs git push origin --delete
```

`git branch -r --merged` lists all merged remotes.
`grep origin` tells the command to include origin.
`grep -v master` tells the command to exclude master.
`xargs git push origin --delete` tells the command to delete the list of remotes.

All together, I expect this to gather all merged remotes and delete them.

When I run the above command, I receive the following for every merged remote;

```
error: unable to delete 'origin/myBranch-1234': remote ref does not exist
error: unable to delete 'origin/myBranch-1235': remote ref does not exist
error: unable to delete 'origin/myBranch-1236': remote ref does not exist
error: unable to delete 'origin/myBranch-1237': remote ref does not exist
... etc
```

However these remotes do exist and I can checkout each of them.  Many sites and people recommend that I run `git fetch --prune` to clean up missing references.  This does nothing because all of these remotes exist.

### So I ask you, dear stack exchange;

- Why can I delete one remote, but not many?
- Is my command correct?

I think I'm missing something small.  Every time I research this, it seems like I'm doing this correctly, but I'm getting the above errors.

- [Delete local and Remote Branches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2003505/delete-a-git-branch-both-locally-and-remotely)
- [gist Delete Merged Remotes](https://gist.github.com/schacon/942899)

Answer (score 245):

You may need to prune your local "cache" of remote branches first.  Try running:

`git fetch -p origin`

before deleting.

Comment: That solved it for me, thanks! However, why is it not updating when I fetch without `--prune`? In my opinion that's pretty misleading

Comment: Just a note for people arriving here from a search - while this is clearly useful to the majority who land here, it's not actually correct in terms of the original issue - the OP's problem was that his command incorrectly included `origin/` in the branch names, as described/resolved in other answers.

Answer (score 113):

Are those branches removed from the remote (origin)? If yes, you can simply do

```
git fetch --prune origin
```

Otherwise they might return even after you delete them locally.

**Update:** Looking at your command again, it looks like you're building it incorrectly. You probably want

```
git push origin --delete myBranch-1234
```

but instead you are doing something like

```
git push origin --delete origin/myBranch-1234
```

Comment: None of the branches are removed in origin.  I can checkout any of them.

Comment: This command works for me:
`git push --delete origin myBranch-1234`.

When I try to delete all merged branches by 
`git branch -r --merged | grep origin | grep -v master | xargs git push origin --delete`,
It tells me that the remote ref does not exist.

Comment: yes, because you execute different commands in the second case.

Comment: I don't understand your point.  I know that I'm using two different commands.  The second case is getting all merged remotes with `git branch -r --merged` and then I am trying to delete them with `xargs git push origin --delete`.  The command is attempting to delete the remotes except that it thinks the `remote ref does not exist`.

Comment: in your second, piped command, put echo right next to `xargs` to see what is actually executed.

Comment: I included the `echo` as you recommended to create this command: `git branch -r --merged | grep origin | grep -v master | grep -v dev | echo xargs git push --delete origin` and it returned `xargs git push --delete origin`.  This is what I expected to see.  I also tried `... | xargs git push --delete origin/myBranch-1234` and it still resulted in `remote ref does not exist` as I've explained in my summary above.

Comment: @Jqw You cannot include the `origin/` prefix on the branch name, git already knows you're working with origin's branches since you are running `git push origin`.  Mykola's suggestion was to make the last part of the command `xargs echo`, rather than `echo xargs [...]`.

Answer (score 15):

Use `sed` to remove 'origin/' part and change a lttile `xargs` part.

```
git branch -r --merged | grep origin | grep -v -e master | sed s/origin\\/// |  xargs -I{} git push origin --delete {}
```