# How to delete git branch if I`m already deleted remote repo?

Tags: git, github

I created second repo for my project on github,
first locates on another resource
I pushed my code on github,
after this I realized my mistake and deleted this repo by hands, but it`s still visible in my IDE
I tried to delete github/mybranch from my IDE but got answer

> "Failed to delete remote branch github/mybranch repository
>   https://github.com/myaccount/myproject.git/" not found"

Answers from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10292480/when-deleting-remote-git-branch-error-unable-to-push-to-unqualified-destinatio/10293324) didnot help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check VCS -> Git -> Remotes, there you can edit / delete your github link to your repository or add a new link to a new one

Comment: Sounds familiar to me. I'm glad I could help

Answer (score 0):

Running `git remote -v` will usually show something like:

```
origin  git@github.com:myaccount/myproject.git (fetch)
origin  git@github.com:myaccount/myproject.git (push)
```

If it is empty, you can simply add back your remote with:

```
git remote origin git@github.com:myaccount/myproject.git
```

Your IDE will have similar options somewhere to add remotes.