# Error: Trying to write ref refs/heads/test with nonexistant object

Tags: git, github

I am trying to delete my remote branches. I have three of this kind

**remotes/origin/test**

But none of them can be deleted. I've searched for common solutions and I have found this suggestions:

`git push origin :test`

and

`git push origin test --delete`

By trying these out, I get this error:

> $ git push origin test --delete
>
> >> Receiving push
>
> ERROR: error: Trying to write ref refs/heads/test with nonexistant object 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000
>
> fatal: Cannot update the ref 'refs/heads/test'.
>
> To ssh:*Repository*
>
> ! [remote rejected] test (pre-receive hook declined)
>
> error: failed to push some refs to '*Repository*'

I hope someone knows how to solve this problem. Thank you! :)

Comment: is there a pre-receive hook in play on the remote side? (the output you pasted seem to indicate as much).  It looks like it's trying to do something with the new commit hash (which for deletes is 000000)

Comment: i am trying to delete a branch related to a project stored by my new clod hoster, which makes use of a git alias called "cctrlapp" <b>https://www.cloudcontrol.com/documentation/getting-started/git-version-control</b> 

I've also created a git remote using: 
<b>git remote add cctrl REPO_URL</b>

could there be a misunderstanding for git trying to delete this remote branch? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
git push origin :test
```

deletes the test branch on the origin remote. Also you need to delete the branch locally

```
 git branch -d test
```

Follow [cleaning up old remote git branches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3184555/cleaning-up-old-remote-git-branches)

Comment: `--delete` flag is equivalent to the `:<branch>` syntax and Kevin states he's tried both and they fail.

Comment: Yes, both of them failed. I've cloned my project from my cloud hosters repository. I do not have any local branches called <b>test</b>. I only wanted to clean my git by deleting remote branches, which i don't need any more. But every try failed.

Comment: checkout http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3184555/cleaning-up-old-remote-git-branches @KevinKatzke

Comment: Thank you GhostRider :) i've posted a new answer with the solution and small question. It would be great if you could give me another litte hint :)