# git showing branches that are not on github anymore

Tags: git, github, git-branch

after running

```
git fetch
```

I can see some branches which are not (anymore) on GitHub (using `git branch -a`). Why is this? How can I resolve this? It's especially uncomfortable in git-cola, where I can see all these dead branches.

Comment: aren't these local branches ?

Comment: Possible duplicate (but applied to GitHub): http://stackoverflow.com/a/3184742/1012381

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If there are 'dead' branches that were deleted from another developer/machine, you need to prune your local version of the repository:

```
git remote prune origin
```