# windows github tool - use branch unpublish or delete?

Tags: windows, github, git-branch

I'm new to Github and I've been using the [**windows github tool**](http://windows.github.com/) which has proved a great help and handled a lot of things like SSH keys, prompts commits, discard a commit, revert commit, and it has a combined mechanism of pull+merge & push (sync), and a lot!

I'm learning it and trying to get its internal git command level executions. The other day, I merged a hotfix branch and then wanted to delete it -

```
git branch -d hotfix
```

I need to know how to delete it from the server as well. What are the git equivalents of the following two actions available in manage branch in the windows tool -

> - **Unpublish** a branch - remove only from the server
> - **Delete** a branch - remove locally and on server

Another thing I doubt is that the above git command was unable to remove the branch locally. I executed it, it removed the branch (didn't show in **$ git branch**) but if I restart the tool, the branch was still there! Was that a glitch?

*If someone has been using these, can you pls suggest the best approach (I don't want to be totally dependent on the tool, I want to learn git as well).*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In addition to

```
git branch -d hotfix
```

you also can remove it from GitHub:

```
git push origin --delete hotfix
```

You can see more at "[How do I delete a Git branch both locally and in GitHub?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2003505/how-do-i-delete-a-git-branch-both-locally-and-in-github/2003515#2003515)"

---

If you have already deleted branches locally, a simple:

```
git push --prune origin
```

is enough to clean those same branches on your GitHub repo.

---

The opposite situation is when you have deleted branches on GitHub, while they are still on your local repo.
In that case:

```
git remote prune origin
```

See "[cleaning up old remote git branches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3184555/cleaning-up-old-remote-git-branches/3184742#3184742)".

Comment: delete local doesn't work "error: Cannot delete branch 'xxx' checked out c:\users.....

Comment: @user2568374 Yes, you cannot delete a local branch which is *also* currently used (checked out). First checkout another branch.