# If we delete a branch on the server, can we automatically delete it in our local copy?

Tags: git, github, branch

Usually, when I send Pull Requests on github, I would create a branch, make my changes, then ask them to merge that branch into their repo.

Once that is done, on Github, I delete the branch (but github just hides it). I then permanently delete the branch on the Github site.

Now that the remote branch is gone, how I can synchronize my local repo with the remote? I have tried fetching and pulling, but that does not delete the branches in my local repo.

Will I have to manually delete them from my repo, or is there some way to sync it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try a:

```
git remote prune origin
```

(assuming the remote 'origin' references your GitHub repo)

This is explained in "[cleaning up old remote git branches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3184555/cleaning-up-old-remote-git-branches/3184742#3184742)" (`git branch -d localbranch`)

I don't know of a native git command which would do both.
Only a script like "[**`git_remote_branch`**](https://github.com/webmat/git_remote_branch)" would delete a branch both on GitHub and locally

delete (aliases: destroy, kill, remove, rm)

> Delete the remote branch then delete the local branch.
>   The local branch is not deleted if there are pending changes.

```
$ grb delete branch_name [origin_server]
```

Comment: That stopped all those branches from showing up on `origin` when I run `git branch -a`, but the branches still exists in my local repo.

Comment: @F21 true. I have edited my question to make this limitation more visible, and to suggest a possible solution.

Answer (score 0):

Another option to clear (on your local) deleted branches on the server could be

**git fetch –p**

Hope this helps.