# How to delete a remote branch using Git?

Tags: git, branch, git-branch

I know this has been covered before, but I have tried the following and can't seem to delete the remote branch.

```
aly@neon:~/workspace/3DOD_VARIANCE$ git branch -a
* master
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  remotes/origin/master
  remotes/origin/multi_gauss_at_nodes
  remotes/origin/old-state-with-mean-deviation-from-centre
  remotes/origin/variance-branch


aly@neon:~/workspace/3DOD_VARIANCE$ git branch -r -d origin/old-state-with-mean-deviation-from-centre Deleted remote branch origin/old-state-with-mean-deviation-from-centre (was 0ed90b2).


Fetching origin
From https://bitbucket.org/alykhantejani/3dobjectdetection
 * [new branch]      old-state-with-mean-deviation-from-centre -> origin/old-state-with-mean-deviation-from-centre
```

As you can see the branch has been fetched again. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Also, as a side note, is there a way for me to check if this branch has already been merged back into master before I delete?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I delete a Git branch both locally and in GitHub?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2003505/how-do-i-delete-a-git-branch-both-locally-and-in-github)

Comment: @Livius Hi, yes I referred to this question first, but with no luck

Comment: “No luck” is not a helpful error report. Also why does your question not state that you tried the solution given there?

Comment: @Chronial, Well "no luck" in this case is well documented in the question as I give the full command line history...

Comment: The linked answers explain to use `git push`. I do not see one `git push` in your question. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The full push command is the following

```
git push <remote name> <local branch>:<remote branch>
```

Just send "no branch at all" to the remote server that way:

```
git push origin :old-state-with-mean-deviation-from-centre
```

For the sidenote : git prevents you to delete branch that has not been merged when you use "git branch -d " (and tells you to use -D if you are really sure to delete it anyway).

Also notice the `git branch -d -r <branch name>` delete the references in your .git folder (and not the real branch located on the remote server), that's why a new fetch will re create it

Comment: Thanks, this has solved the problem. Please can you emphasize that the origin/ qualifier is not needed on the remote branch name as this was making it fail for me.

Comment: all what you can do with "branch" command concerns your local repository, i.e. the .git folder. `git branch -d -r origin/master` concerns the file .git/refs/remotes/origin/master (which contains a sha1) will be deleted, but not the one on the server (because no branch are named "origin/master" which stands for part of the branch name).
if you type `git push :origin/old-branch` it will try to remove the branch "origin/old-branch" (taking origin as a namespace) which does not exists.

Comment: There is now a `--delete` parameter. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71649399/4653485).

Answer (score 53):

To delete a remote branch run following:

```
git push origin :branch-to-delete
```

The trick is in colon

Comment: any idea on how to check that this branch has been merged into master before I delete?

Comment: git branch --contains that-branch. It will give u list of branches, that contain that branch, If ur branch is in the list, u can delete it.

Comment: Tried the above command and get the following:  unable to push to unqualified destination: origin/old-state-with-mean-deviation-from-centre The destination refspec neither matches an existing ref on the remote nor
begins with refs/

Comment: it seems like that branch doesnt exist on the server anymore. U should update ur local branch list. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3184555/cleaning-up-old-remote-git-branches

run this: git remote prune origin

Comment: Found the solution, I was typing :origin/old-state... the origin is not needed.

Answer (score 13):

From [@Matthew Rankin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2003515/4653485):

As of [Git v1.7.0](https://github.com/gitster/git/blob/master/Documentation/RelNotes/1.7.0.txt), you can delete a remote branch using

```
$ git push <remote_name> --delete <branch_name>
```

Answer (score 7):

try

```
git push origin :remote_branch_to_be_deleted
```