# git - delete local tracking

Tags: git, git-remote

I've deleted some remote branches (`dev/featureA` and `dev/featureB`) however when I run `git remote show origin` I still see them being listed under the local branches section. E.g.

```
$ git remote show origin

Local branches configured for 'git pull':
  dev/featureA                  merges with remote dev/featureA
  dev/featureB                  merges with remote dev/featureB
```

Do I need to disable tracking or something similar?

Answer (score 4):

This one worked for me

```
 git branch -r -d dev/featureA
```

Answer (score 3):

To remove the remote repository from being tracked all together locally, do the following:
`git remote remove <remoteRepo>`

To explicitly remove only the upstream tracking for a specific local branch , do the following:
`git branch --unset-upstream <branch name>`

`git branch --unset-upstream dev/featureA`

To remove all stale local branches that are not longer available at the remote, do the following:

`git remote prune <remoteRepo>`

I'd be careful with the last one and do a `--dry-run` of the prune first...

More information is available 
http://git-scm.com/docs/git-branch

and

http://git-scm.com/docs/git-remote

Answer (score 2):

Snow try with the next command:

```
git fetch origin --prune
```

This command is to remove deleted branches.
If not, please visit this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3184555/cleaning-up-old-remote-git-branches) and see if some of those command could help you.
Regards!

Comment: did not work for me fatal: Refusing to fetch into current branch refs/heads/<branchName> of non-bare repository

Comment: Perfect.     Deleted the local tracking branches that had no associated branches on the remote server.