# How to clear git caches?

Tags: git

When I list my branches with `git branch -a`, git shows me remote branches I can't actually find on my remote(gitlab). I tried to checkout and track those branches, and to my big surprise, git did it. But when I do for example `git push origin :branch_name`, git says that the remote ref does not exist, thus proving that I do not have those branches in my remote. Hence I have a question, are those branches stored in some kind a local cache? And if yes, how to clear it?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Use `git fetch -p` to prune your local caches

Answer (score 8):

Like mentioned on [cleaning up old remote git branches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3184555/cleaning-up-old-remote-git-branches), you should use `git remote prune origin`.

I didn't use the other two commands mentioned there.

Answer (score 3):

I had a weird issue on macOS where I would get phantom Uppercase versions of branches, e.g. my remote branch listing would show `Ben/some-branch` locally, but the server would show `ben/some-branch`.

`git remote prune origin` would (correctly) remove them, but `git fetch --prune` would (incorrectly) bring them right back. Very weird.

Best I can tell, at some point in the past, I had a `Ben/something` branch, but because the *default macOS filesystem is case-insensitive*, the `.git` metadata was hanging onto a (capitalized) `.git/refs/remotes/origin/Ben` folder and using it for the (lowercase) remote branch refs.

`rm -rf .git/refs/remotes/origin/Ben && git fetch` put me back in order.

Comment: Thank you! this is the only answer that helped me with my phantom Uppercase version of branch. It was super annoying.

Answer (score 0):

You can clear the deleted branch data from your Git repository using the `git gc` command.

```
git gc
```

By default, `git gc` will clean up any unreachable objects and perform other optimizations. If you want to run a more aggressive garbage collection operation, you can use the `--aggressive` option:

```
git gc --aggressive
```

Answer (score 0):

Those are the commands you need!

```
git gc --aggressive
git fetch -p 
git rm -r --cached .
```