# After using git fetch only to have a look at others' work, how to get rid of fetched branches?

Tags: git, git-branch, git-fetch

I have a project with a friend with only one branch, `master`. My friend last worked on the project and I fetched (`git fetch`) his work just to have a look. This created a branch called `origin/master`:

```
Project ps1$ git branch -a
  * master
    remotes/origin/master
```

I checked it out (`git checkout origin/master`) and I don't agree with everything that was done, so I don't want to merge now. I'm going to let my friend work more on it. I tried to delete this fetched branch just to clean up, using either

```
git branch -d remotes/origin/master
```

or

```
git branch -d origin/master
```

but it said the branch was not found in both cases. How do I get rid of this branch (should I even do this?)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [cleaning up old remote git branches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3184555/cleaning-up-old-remote-git-branches)

Comment: Just don't use `-a`.  That is showing you branches in your friend's repo. If you have your friend's branch setup as a remote and don't want to see anything, do a `git remote remove`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`git branch -rd origin/master` should work.

From the [documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-branch):

> Use `-r` together with `-d` to delete remote-tracking branches. Note, that
>   it only makes sense to delete remote-tracking branches if they no
>   longer exist in the remote repository or if *git fetch* was configured
>   not to fetch them again.

Comment: Thanks! So this will only delete my local remote-tracking branch `origin/master` right? This won't affect the remote repo at all?