# A branch, deleted on gitlab, still exists in the command line?

Tags: git, gitlab, git-branch

After merging a development branch devBranchA into the master, I deleted it on the web interface (precisely, on gitlab.com). If I then do a `git branch -r` to list all remote branches, I get that:

```
origin/HEAD -> origin/master
origin/devBranchA
```

Why  is that so? I already tried a `git pull`, but it did not shown any difference.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [cleaning up old remote git branches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3184555/cleaning-up-old-remote-git-branches)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+remove+local+and+remote+branches

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `git remote prune origin` to remove the deleted remote branches from your local repo.

Use `git branch -d <branch-name>` to delete the local branch.