# Why does a deleted remote branch in git still show up when you do a 'git branch -a?

Tags: git

I'm trying to delete a branch on git both locally and remotely.  And I think I've been successful.  Thing is it still shows up remotely when I do a 'git branch -a'

I did this to delete it locally:

```
git branch -d branchToDelete
```

and this to delete it remotely:

```
git push origin --delete branchToDelete
```

I think I deleted it successfully on both ends.

If I do
git pull branchToDelete

I get the following
fatal: 'branchToDelete' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Which I thought means it no longer exists remotely?

But if I do

```
git branch -a
```

Then it still shows up in the list

```
remotes/origin/branchToDelete
```

So why does it keep showing up if it's deleted both locally and remotely?

And yes, the branch is/was named the same both locally and remotely.

Thanks much

Comment: You could try doing a `git fetch` just in case it might be necessary to sync up your tracking branches with the remote after doing the remote deletion.

Comment: It should be ok how you do it. What version of git are you using?

Comment: Was recently discussed: https://stackoverflow.com/q/69816331/7976758 Found in https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=%5bgit%5d%20deleted%20branch

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to do a `git fetch -p` to prune (remove) local tracking branches of remote branches that have been deleted.

Comment: When using `git push` with `--delete` this shouldn't be necessary

Comment: @kapsiR: yes, but only for the one repository from which you (*you*, not someone else) ran `git push --delete`: probably in this case someone else did the delete, or Tim (OP) did it from another repository, etc.