# Branch is not showing up in BitBucket but is showing in git bash

Tags: git, bitbucket

My BitBucket repository does not show several branches but running git locally in bash:

```bash
git fetch --all; git branch -a;
```

does show those remote branches.

When I try deleting them in git locally:

```bash
git push origin --delete <name_of_branch>
```

I get an error that these branches are not found.

Could these branches be cached locally and can this cache be cleared ?

Comment: Maybe the branches are local and are not on the repo? Try just deleting them `git branch -d <name_of_branch>`?

Comment: If [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44129766/184546) helps you, then this is a dup of that question.

Comment: A `git push origin --delete` is a request that the other Git delete something. If it's not there, there's nothing to delete, which explains your error. Remember that a *remote-tracking name* like `origin/foo` is *local to your personal Git repository* and is remembering that there is, or was at one time, a *branch* `foo` over on `origin`.

Comment: Meanwhile, as a general rule, don't use `--all`, which doesn't mean what you think it means, with `git fetch` or `git pull`. See [the `git fetch` documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch) for specifics on what it actually means. (If you already know it means "all remotes", not "all branches", this comment is only addressed at other readers of this question.)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have a local branch that has not been pushed to the remote.

If the goal is to delete local branch `mybranch` use a command like:

```bash
$ git branch -D mybranch
```

Comment: I think the OP means that `origin/foo` shows up as a remote-tracking name. Since `git branch -D` only deletes *local* branch names, this won't help. However, `git fetch --prune` or `git branch -r -D` would work.